# Conversion of output activation with Softmax produces similar values

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, softmax

I trained a simple reccurent network (62 input units, 124 hidden/context units, 62 output units) to predict the subsequent word in a sentence. I used the sigmoid activation function. 
For some various and strange reasons, it was not possible to apply softmax during training. My professor suggested, that I could apply softmax afterwards to the networks output. The matrix has 576 rows and 62 coloumns. 
So I implemented softmax in R in the following way:

```
softmax <- function(outVec = NULL){
  s.vec <- exp(outVec)/sum(exp(outVec))
  return(s.vec)
}

softmax_complete <- function(vec = NULL){
  softmaxed.vec <- matrix(apply(vec, 1, softmax), ncol=dim(vec)[2], nrow=dim(vec)[1])
  return(softmaxed.vec)
}
```

Each row of the matrix which softmax_complete() returns, sums correctly to 1. The problem is, that for each row, my function producing values which are very similar to each other. Its not possible to validate the networks performance because the values are almost "the same".

Here is some small example data. Its from the second row of the networks output. Softmax was not applied yet.

```
output.vec <- c(0.2371531427, 0.0085829534, 0.0007576860, 0.0027021256, 0.0025776778, 0.0014593119, 0.0019006504, 0.0403518006,
                0.0024586972, 0.0517364480, 0.0012057235, 0.0950696915, 0.0025749709, 0.0008823058, 0.0005064047, 0.0014039490,
                0.0013259919, 0.0014723240, 0.0011820868, 0.0011805159, 0.0009319001, 0.0022884205, 0.0023589570, 0.0020189525,
                0.0015377736, 0.0937648788, 0.0012874968, 0.0443032309, 0.0012919122, 0.0897148922, 0.0022041877, 0.0444274731,
                0.0014143962, 0.0361100733, 0.0020817134, 0.0447632931, 0.0009620183, 0.0011552101, 0.0016173105, 0.0016870035,
                0.0011272663, 0.0019183536, 0.0017270016, 0.0011056620, 0.0007743868, 0.0026786255, 0.0019340677, 0.0010532230,
                0.0014585924, 0.0386148430, 0.0012295874, 0.0390544645, 0.0017903288, 0.0967107117, 0.0013074477, 0.0006164946,
                0.0001758277, 0.0001023397, 0.0004014068, 0.0004558225, 0.0003554984, 0.0001830685)
```

When I apply softmax to that row I get the following results:

```
[1] 0.01585984 0.01583950 0.01567646 0.01583540 0.01735750 0.01579704 0.01587178 0.01589101 0.01586093 0.01590457
[11] 0.01586255 0.01637181 0.01590217 0.01584308 0.01570456 0.01581733 0.01952223 0.01590497 0.01970620 0.01578586
[21] 0.01610417 0.01591379 0.01588095 0.01584309 0.01567710 0.01582956 0.01650858 0.01573117 0.01589502 0.01608836
[31] 0.01574208 0.01582079 0.01584367 0.01569571 0.01583481 0.01596172 0.01577246 0.01586151 0.01605467 0.01574746
[41] 0.01586397 0.01581472 0.01576479 0.01580914 0.01583660 0.01566672 0.01584366 0.02017004 0.01585517 0.02007705
[51] 0.01580263 0.01583277 0.01580424 0.01583763 0.01587117 0.01568283 0.01583775 0.01595945 0.01587471 0.01575585
[61] 0.01584288 0.01577770
```

The row sum is 1.000703. And for another row which is not depicted in the sample above, the row sum is 0.9976472. What am I doing wrong?

Maybe you guys have an idea to fix that issue. Thank you in advance for your time and help :-)

regards, Matthias

EDIT:

This is how I create the Elman Net by RSNNS:

```
elman<-rsnnsObjectFactory(subclass=c("elman"), nInputs=inputNeurons, maxit=maxIterations, 
                     initFunc="JE_Weights", initFuncParams=c(0.15, -0.15, 0, 1.0, 0.5), 
                     learnFunc="JE_BP", learnFuncParams=c(learnRate),
                     updateFunc="JE_Order", updateFuncParams=c(0),
                     shufflePatterns=FALSE, computeIterativeError=FALSE) 
  elman$archParams <- list(size=hiddenNeurons)
  elman$snnsObject$elman_createNet(c(inputNeurons, hiddenNeurons, outputNeurons),c(1,1,1),FALSE)
  elman$snnsObject$initializeNet(c(0.15, -0.15, 0, 1.0, 0.5), initFunc="JE_Weights") 
  elman$snnsObject$setUnitDefaults(1,0,1,0,1,"Act_Logistic","Out_Identity")
  elman$snnsObject$setTTypeUnitsActFunc("UNIT_INPUT", "Act_Logistic")
  elman$snnsObject$setTTypeUnitsActFunc("UNIT_SPECIAL_H", "Act_Identity")
  elman$snnsObject$setTTypeUnitsActFunc("UNIT_OUTPUT", "Act_Logistic")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more concise version of softmax would be:

```
softmax <- function(x){
  score.exp <- exp(x)
  probs <-sweep(score.exp, 1, rowSums(score.exp), '/')
  return(probs)
}
```

which you could now pass the matrix directly in.  Now, looking at the vector you provided.

```
res <- softmax(matrix(output.vec, nrow=1))
sum(res)
[1] 1
```

However, it still appears that there isn't much difference in your values.  It appears to me that for this particular sample this isn't much information provided by your RNN.  According to this, the most likely 'class' is the first class at probability of 2%.

I would recommend trying it across you entire dataset using the function above.

This is all assuming many things on your implementation of the neural net.  It would be helpful if you could provide a reference to the software you used and at least what parameters you were setting.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

I use the _Stuttgart Neuronal Network Simulator for R (RSNNS)_ to build the network. The weights are randomly generated between -0.15 und 0.15. The learning rate was set to 0.1. I used standard backpropagation for training but without Cross-Entropy (its currently not provided by RSNNS). The activation function for the hidden-, input- and output units is sigmoid and for the context units its identity.

Comment: The inputs are provided within a matrix with orthogonal rows. Each coloumn represents a single word, a row represents a word in a sentence. Only a single bit in a row is active (1) and flags that specific word. The others are zero in that row. I tried your solution but I got the same results. The reason why I want to use softmax is that I have some values sum to >1 so I cannot use log odds for my mixed linear model.

Comment: @matze Can you just provide the actual call?  I assume you are using `RSNNS::mlp`?

Comment: When I measure the networks performance without softmax, I get useful results. The formula I use is the _Grammatical Prediction Error_ (Christiansen & Chater, 1999). It takes hits, misses and false alarms into account and compares them to the word probabilities generated by a context free grammer (SLG, Rohde, 1999). But some values, as I mentioned above, sum up to >1 and I have the fear that the results are not interpretable as probabilities and because of this I could draw a false conclusion.

Comment: I edited my question to show the complete function call to create the elman net by RSNNS.

Comment: I think it may be because you are applying the `Act_Logistic` function on the output layer.  I think it would need to be the raw values prior to using `softmax` for it to work correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Maybe I'll try the identity function at the output layer and apply softmax afterwards. 

Do you think, that the approach with the logistic function are distorting my data? Is there a big difference between logistic and softmax respectivly to analyze the output for interpretation?

Comment: The main distinction is that the output of `softmax` can be directly interpreted as probabilities for classification.  The `logistic` method is more for a regression problem.